# Permission denied while deploying

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, vlad-deployer

I am getting the following error while deploying.

Deploy command:

```
bundle exec rake current vlad:deploy
```

Error:

```
bash: script/delayed_delta: Permission denied
rake aborted!
execution failed with status 126: ssh deploy@something.com source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm rvmrc trust /home/deploy/something.com.com/current && cd /home/deploy/something.com.com/current && rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p0@something && RAILS_ENV=current script/delayed_delta stop
```

What might be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

When i run the following command on script/delayed_delta the permissions were changed but still i get the error.

```
chmod +x script/delayed_delta
```

ERROR:

```
bash: script/delayed_job: Permission denied rake aborted! execution failed with status 126: ssh deploy@something.com source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm rvmrc trust /home/deploy/something.com/current && cd /home/deploy/something.com/current && rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p0@something && if [[ -f script/delayed_job ]] ; then RAILS_ENV=current script/delayed_job stop ; fi
```

The permissions in script directory are:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 delayed_delta
-rw-rw-r-- 1 delayed_job
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rails
```

Comment: What permissions are on `script/delayed_delta`?

Comment: You can use `ls -l` and look in the first column.

Comment: You need to add execute permissions if it's a script. Try `chmod +x script/delayed_delta`.

Comment: @alex you can check the update section in the question.

Comment: Add the permissions to each script.

Comment: @alex the permissions are saved OK. but when i deploy again in the end the permissions are changes to old permissions due to which i get again the same error.

Comment: If script/delayed_delta is part of the application you're deploying, do `chmod +x script/delayed_delta` not on your server, but in your application, then commit, then try deploying again.